# AWS API Request has expired

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am attempting to retrieve information about an Amazon Store item. I believe I have created a Javascript program that can produce properly formatted requests using my AWS credentials. However, Amazon responds to my requests with "Request has expired. Timestamp date is xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ."

According to documentation, timestamps are valid for 15 minutes, and the UTC time I am submitting is definitely not 15 minutes off.

Here is one of my example requests: 
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=[MY-ACCESS-KEY-ID]&AssociateTag=[MY-ASSOCIATE-TAG]&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=B00008OE6I&Timestamp=2017-06-12T17%3A15%3A41Z&Signature=PdCAjiE%2Bl7tsQDY8SzqOWiiLPFI%3D

Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: How do you get your AWS creds for call?

Comment: I got my authentication keys by going to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credential and clicking "Create New Access Key"

Comment: I got my "Associate Tag" by going to https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/home and using the string after "Store:" in the top right corner.

Comment: Well, what does really authenticate you there, is a signature. How do you calculate it, could you elaborate?

Comment: Alright, I figured out my issue...it was just a dumb mistake on my part. I thought I was having issues figuring out the complex authentication, but actually I just forgot that getMonth() starts at index 0, but Amazon wants moths starting at index 1, so my dates were all wrong.